# !IsPostBack event from Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events, postback

I am using ASP.NET

I have to set the value of a variable `[testVar]` into Javascript on page load. only for the first time when the page load. Just like `!IsPostBack` event on code side.

From next postback this function of Javascript should not call. Please let me know how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to your ASPX page:

```
<% if (!this.IsPostBack) %>
<% { %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("<%= this.timeVar.ClientID %>").value = '1/1/2010';
    </script>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have to set the value of a hidden variable in my aspx page. Hidden variable name is "timeVar". How to set the value, please suggest

Comment: I am trying to put this between <script> tag, but no luck  var TimeVar =document.getElementById('<%= this.timeVar.ClientID %>');   
     TimeVar.value= "1/1/2010";

Comment: changed my answer a bit to include your code snippet. @zerotoinfinite

Comment: I put this code on the aspx page, I also put the alert under it. But this event is not firing . :-( please help

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite: Have you checked client side HTML code with Firebug? Can you do that now?